# ffmpeg Convert audio files to mp3 using ffmpeg same quality

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I convert audio files to mp3 with original file's audio quality?

```
ffmpeg -i audio.ogg -f mp3 newfile.mp3
```

I want to know is that code converts with same quality?

Comment: This has been [crossposted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012173/ffmpeg-convert-audio-files-to-mp3-using-ffmpeg-same-quality) to SO.